# Solr SpellCheck - how can I autoquery the indexes on the popular suggestions

Tags: solr

I have successfully configured the Solr SpellCheck component, and am getting the expected suggestions.  Using the spellcheck extended results, I get the number of hits on each sugesstion as well.    Now, my question is if I want to query my indexes using the most popular (First two or three) sugesstions, how can I do that?  Do I have to make another query myself by using the suggested words, or does solr provide an easier way to query the indexes using the most popular suggested words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does not provide an implementation to query automatically on the suggested terms.
You would have to requery for the suggestions to get back the results.

Comment: Cool Thanks! I think by default, Solr takes the top suggestion and queries the indexes, if the spellcheck.collate flag is true.  But it would be nice to have feature, if there is an option for us to query solr based on the second to best suggestion as well, by using a similar flag.